# Filenet Open a particulate AddCase Page form script adapter

Tags: javascript, filenet-p8, filenet, ibm-case-manager

I am looking a way to open a particulate addcase on addcase page from Event Action , i was trying with "icm.OpenPage"

```
try{

        solution.retrieveCaseType("Demo_ApprovalCase", function(caseType) {
            solution.createNewCaseEditable(caseType, function(pendingCaseEditable) {
                modified_payload = {
                    caseEditable: pendingCaseEditable,
                    caseType: caseType,
                    coordination: new icm.util.Coordination(),
                    eventName: "icm.SendNewCaseInfo",
                    eventType: "broadcast"
                };

                var subject = new dojox.uuid.Uuid(dojox.uuid.generateRandomUuid());

                var targetosname = solution.targetObjectStore.objectStoreName;
                self.onBroadcastEvent(icm.OpenPage, {

                    pageClassName: "CMTOS/Demo/CRDemo",
                    pageType: "caseNewPage",
                    subject: subject,
                    pageTitle: "Add Case Custom",
                    pageContext: {
                        solution: self.solution,
                        role: self.role
                    },
                    crossPageEventName: "icm.SendNewCaseInfo",
                    crossPageEventPayload: modified_payload
                });

            });

        });
        }catch (Error) {

        console.log(Error);
        }
```

I got a error saying "eventName is undefined".
I have try with "icm.OpenAddCasePage" event to get this result by with the example i found

```
{"ICM_ACTION_COMPATIBLE": true,
    "context": null,
    "name": "Custom Add Case Action",
    "description": "An action to add cases from other solution",
    "properties": [
       {
          "id": "label",
          "title": "Add a custom Case",
          "defaultValue": "Custom Add Case",
          "type": "string",
          "isLocalized":false
       },
       {
          "id": "solution",
          "title": "Solution",
          "type": "string",
          "isLocalized":false
       },
       {
          "id": "caseType",
          "title": "Case Type",
          "defaultValue": "",
          "type": "string",
          "isLocalized":false
       }
    ],
    "events":[
       {
          "id":"icm.OpenAddCasePage",
          "title":"Open Add custom Case Page",
          "direction":"published",
          "type":"broadcast",
          "description":"Open Add Custom Case Page"
       }
    ]
};
```

But i didn't get any output.I am looking a way to do BroadcastEvent or call function so i can open a particulate addcase.

Comment: The "eventName is undefined" error is likely to come from the fact that icm.OpenPage evalutes undefined. You forgot the qoutes - "icm.OpenPage".

Comment: Yes Ivo , it worked.thanks for helping as always.